# How to fix the custom function in google spreadsheet when the script can't take input?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, custom-function, alpha-vantage

I wrote a custom function from the google app script. It's supposed to take value inside from the cell and print JSON data. It succeeded in working in the backend. However, I can't put any input from the front end.

```
=STOCKC(AMD)
```

This is the custom function I want to make inside the google sheets. It's supposed to extract data from the JSON data.

```
    function STOCKC(symbol){
    //this is the testcase for the backend
        //var symbol = "AMD";
        symbol = encodeURI(symbol);
       var url = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_WEEKLY&symbol="+symbol+"&apikey="+api_key;
       var responseUrl = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
       var response = responseUrl.getContentText();
       var stockdata = JSON.parse(response);
       var closepricear = new Array();

      if(Object.keys(stockdata).length > 1){
  var help = Object.keys(stockdata)[1];
    for(var i = 0; i < Object.keys(stockdata[help]).length; i++){
      var helpVal = Object.keys(stockdata[help])[i];
      var open = Object.keys(stockdata[help][helpVal])[0];
      var close = Object.keys(stockdata[help][helpVal])[3];
      var low = Object.keys(stockdata[help][helpVal])[2];
      var volume = Object.keys(stockdata[help][helpVal])[4];
      var high = Object.keys(stockdata[help][helpVal])[1];
      var date = Object.keys(stockdata[help]);

     closepricear.push({"close":stockdata[help][helpVal][close]})
    // closepriceard.push(date)
    }
  }
       Logger.log(closepricear);
       return closepricear;
}
```

The logger.log(closepriear) shows the data I want but the front end won't print.

I get

> reference doesn't exist

error at the front end.

This is the closepriear Logger.log() data. This is what i get when i do the backend test. It's a long list of data consist of the following.

```
[19-07-13 15:52:55:823 PDT] [{close=33.2100}, {close=31.5000}, {close=30.3700}, {close=29.1000}, {close=30.3600}, {close=32.4100}, {close=27.4100}, {close=26.4400}, {close=27.5000}, {close=27.9600}, {close=28.2200}, {close=27.8800}, {close=27.6800}, {close=27.8500}, {close=28.9800}, {close=25.5200}, {close=26.3700}, {close=23.2900},
```

Comment: Can you please provide us with a sample of data that is written into `closepricear`? It might be crucial to debug your code, judging from the code you posted, there should be no issue after TheMaster's answer is implemented

Comment: @OlegValter I just edited it. Let me know if you need more or if i provided the wrong thing.

Comment: Thanks, @jjunbbug! That's the issue, do not return `Objects` as `Array` elements - they won't be displayed, either stringify or map values as `[...,['close',33.2100],...]` - should work (not sure what the desired output is, will post an answer after further clarification)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue#1:

`AMD` doesn't exist at the frontend. It's a `#REF` error(reference doesn't exist), because `AMD` isn't defined. If `AMD` is a plain string literal and not a named range, you need to quote it, just like you did in JavaScript.

```
=STOCKC("AMD")
```

#### Issue#2:

The return variable `closepricear` is a array of objects. You need to return a single value using `JSON.stringify(closepricear)` or a 2D array:

```
closepricear.push([stockdata[help][helpVal][close]])
```

Comment: I completely understand what you're talking about. The #REF sign disappeared but I still have no output coming out. Just plain blank. No error sign or anything. I've never been more confused in my life.

Comment: @jjun Well your return value `closepricear` is just a empty array. Given your code, `Logger.log()` will also log a empty array. I assumed you had some kind of code in `//if and for loop`. If not, It's a empty array and a empty result.

Comment: I had the same suspicion as you! However, I checked the logger.log(). When i use the back end test case var symbol = "AMD"; There's full of data. And it seems like the loop succeeded in extracting the data. That's what I meant when I said it works in backend. That's why I don't think there's a problem with the loops.

Answer (score 2):

**Problem**

To understand what is going on when your custom function pastes values, you can refer to `setValues()` method documentation of the `Range` class (Google Sheets API for apps script), it works pretty much the same way - when you return values from the function, they are interpreted as a two-dimensional `Array` like this (single values are interpreted the same as `setValue()`):

`//pseudo-code;
[ row1: [col1,colN], rowN: [col1,colN] ]`

**Solutions**

1. Reformat your `Array` elements as `[33.2100]` (if you only need values);
2. Use `JSON.stringify()` on your objects before output (if need to preserve obj);

**Useful links**

1. `setValue()` method [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue);
2. `setValues()` method [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues);

Comment: I've tried to set values and this is the error message. "TypeError: Cannot find function setValues in object 1123. (line 30, file "Code")" var range = closepricear.length;
var plz = range.setValues(closepricear); I'm not well versed in javascript so i'm confused how i can solve this.

Comment: @jjunbbug, sorry if my answer caused a confusion - you don't need to actually use `setValues()` method (there is a big difference between how _custom functions_ and _scripts_ operate), it is a point of reference to better understand what's causing the issue. Simply avoid outputting `{key:value}` objects and you should be fine (or stringify them before upload).
If you provide the rest of the function (`if...else` statement and loop) I can show you modifications required if you experience issues

Comment: Hey, the of JSON.stringfy() worked. Thank you so much! However, I'm still confused about how I can reformat the array. The data literally prints like the following: [{close=33.2100}, {close=31.5000}, {close=30.3700}, {close=29.1000}, {close=30.3600}, How would i approach this problem?

Comment: Hi! I think while I was away, TheMaster addressed the second issue of how to reformat to array (basically, you'll have to modify the value used as an argument in `.push()` method)